# ChromiumFx / Cef How to send custom IPC message to renderer process and execute custom c# code

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded

I have been trying to figure out how I can send my own custom IPC message to the renderer process from the browser process so that it can be handled on the UI thread of the renderer process. I want to execute my own c# or c++ code on the actual UI thread of the renderer process.

According to what I have found on some forums, this should be done by implementing the CefRenderProcessHandler interface and then returning an instance of my created class to the GetRendererProcessHandler function in CefApp.

What I can't figure out how to do successfully accomplish this task using ChromiumFx and the ChromiumWebBrowser class. The first issue is that the ChromiumWebBrowser.Initialize function creates the CfxApp object, so there isn't a good place for me to attach to the GetRendererHandlerProcess event and respond with my implementation of the CefRenderProcessHandler interface that is referenced here. http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefRenderProcessHandler.html

According to what I have read, I need to implement the OnProcessMessageReceived function of that interface so that I can properly handle the IPC message when it is received by the Renderer process.

For exploration purposes, I have tried changing the ChromiumWebBrowser.Initialize function to accept a CfxApp object that I pass in so that I can subscribe to the GenRenderHandlerProcess and provide my own class that derives from CfxRenderProcessHandler, but my event handler never gets hit in the browser process.

When that didn't work, I next tried attaching to the OnProcessmessageReceived event in the ChromiumFx RenderProcessHandler class. Now, when I send my message using this code, it hits my breakpoint in the browser process on a thread pool thread (that I assume represents the renderer thread in the actual renderer process).

```
CfrProcessMessage myMessage = CfrProcessMessage.Create("HelloWorld-Remote");
            CfrListValue args = myMessage.ArgumentList;
            bool success = args.SetString(0, "Chris"); 
            success = e.Browser.SendProcessMessage(CfxProcessId.Renderer, myMessage);
```

This doesn't help me because I want to execute custom c# code on the actual renderer processes UI thread.

I put some debug statements in the ChromiumFx's CfxProcessMessageCreateRemoteCall class in the RemoteProcedure method. I can see through my debug statements that this code is getting hit in the actual renderer process when I send the message, but I don't  see how to implement my own custom code to be executed. I can't see where an OnProcessMessageReceived function is ever called in the actual render process.

Is there something that I am missing? Or, is there an example somewhere of how this can be done using ChromiumFx? Here is a link to the documentation for that function.

http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefRenderProcessHandler.html#OnProcessMessageReceived(CefRefPtr%3CCefBrowser%3E,CefProcessId,CefRefPtr%3CCefProcessMessage%3E)

I believe what I am trying to do is what is explained in the cef wiki page here under the Process Runtime Messages header: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage#markdown-header-inter-process-communication-ipc

Thank you for any help/ideas in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at "Entry-point function" section of CEF documentation
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage#markdown-header-entry-point-function

You need to make sure that you set a correct render process handler in the render process entry point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added some additional information to my description about where I am now currently stuck.